# How browser native video fragmentation works?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to secure a video the way it can be played only by authorized users. My application uses token-based authentication. The solution with temporary tokens are no-go this time. On the server, I implemented file streaming which can send specific byte range requested by client script. By JS script I'm able to set header only when the video is starting to load. When scrolling to different frames browser sends 204 Partial Requests and there is no control on headers at all. Which lead to unauthorized request call.

[image]

I was able to implement [MediaSource](http://w3c.github.io/media-source/) based solution. The problem starts when I want to skip preloading video before it can be actually played. To achieve that video must be converted to [fragmented MPEG](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-3.3) or other methods of fragmentation must be used for example [HLS](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) (commonly used in streaming platforms)

So how the user agent is able to scroll through not segmented videos, load video parts without having the right format? Those features are available for standard MP4 files in browsers these days.

Answer (score 0):

HLS has a text file called the manifest that has the time and file name of each segment. A player like HLS.js or videojs convert the time to a filename using the manifest and downloads the correct segment.